# Proving that matrix in equation is invertible

Tags: matrices, algebra-precalculus

The $2 \times 2$ matrix ${A}$ satisfies
${A}^2 - 4 {A} - 7 {I} = {0}$
where ${I}$ is the $2 \times 2$ identity matrix. Prove that ${A}$ is invertible.

I have tried to solve it like a quadratic, but that doesn't work.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 11):

$A^2-4A-7I=0$ $\Longrightarrow$ $A^2-4A=7I$ $\Longrightarrow$ $A\cdot \frac17(A-4I)=I$.  So $A$ is invertible.  Its inverse is $\frac17(A-4I)$.