# On the invertibility of $3\times 3$ matrix $A$ with $A^3 −A^2 + 2A−3I = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

> Prove that $A$ is invertible whenever $A$ is a $3\times3$ matrix with 
>   $$A^3 −A^2 + 2A−3I = 0.$$

This is another past exam paper question I'm stuck on.

Comment: Factor out by $A$.

Comment: Notice: $A(A^2-A+2I)=(A^2-A+2I)A=3I$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving that matrix in equation is invertible](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1297100/proving-that-matrix-in-equation-is-invertible) The equations are different, but the principle is the same.